# Check if columns have equal records in query row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the number of times a certain word occur in a query row.

For example :

```
Name   | Chemistry | Physics   | Biology   | Maths
-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------
John   | Excellent | Good      | Good      | Poor
Kelvin | Excellent | Poor      | Excellent | Poor
```

I want to get something for each row like:

```
Name   | Excellent | Good | Poor  | Max
-------+-----------+------+-------+------
John   |    1      |   2  |   1   | Good
Kelvin |    2      |   0  |   2   | Tie
```

Comment: Could you please provide additonal details i.e. the query and the current result etc

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot with `union all`, then do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    name,
    sum(case when lvl = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end) Excellent,
    sum(case when lvl = 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) Good,
    sum(case when lvl = 'Poor' then 1 else 0 end) Poor
from (
    select name, chemistry lvl from mytable 
    union all select name, physics from mytable 
    union all select name, biology from mytable 
    union all select name, maths from mytable 
) t
group by name
```

To get your last column, it is a little more complex. The shortest solution, is probably to add a new level of querying:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
        when Excellent > Good and Excellent > Poor then 'Excellent'
        when Good > Excellent and Good > Poor then 'Good'
        when Poor > Excellent and Poor > Good then 'Poor'
        else 'Tie'
    end [Max]
from (
    select 
        name,
        sum(case when lvl = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end) Excellent,
        sum(case when lvl = 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) Good,
        sum(case when lvl = 'Poor' then 1 else 0 end) Poor
    from (
        select name, chemistry lvl from mytable 
        union all select name, physics from mytable 
        union all select name, biology from mytable 
        union all select name, maths from mytable 
    ) t
    group by name
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af410fc3bb46f420aa8734afe57d0201)**:

```
name   | Excellent | Good | Poor | Max 
:----- | --------: | ---: | ---: | :---
John   |         1 |    2 |    1 | Good
Kelvin |         2 |    0 |    2 | Tie
```

Comment: Very nice, but I'm doing this for 9 different parameters. Like  Excellent | Very_Good | Good | Average | Fair | Poor | Very_Poor | Fail etc.